# BIOS won't allow SSD as default boot drive

Tags: boot, ssd, ahci

I've been using a Vertex3 SSD as my Windows 7 boot drive in IDE mode for a few months without problems with a ASRock A75M-ITX motherboard.

Today, I ran the Microsoft fix-it to enable the AHCI drivers, changed the SATA controller to AHCI mode in the bios, and rebooted.  It gave me the message

> BOOTMGR missing.  Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to reboot

So I went back to the BIOS and saw that my SSD is no longer listed in the boot priority menu.  However, it shows up and boots fine if I press F11 to bring up the boot menu during the POST and select it.  The first time I did this, Windows told me the AHCI driver was installed and I should reboot.

Currently my computer is usable, with all indications that the SSD and Windows are working properly in AHCI mode, but the drive will not show up in the BIOS boot priority listing, although it is listed elsewhere correctly.  I failed to find any BIOS updates for my motherboard on google.

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: What version of the BIOS does your motherboard have?  Have you contacted ASRock support to see if your issue is a known problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude. http://www.asrock.com/mb/download.asp?Model=A75M-ITX&o=All
At the bottom of the page updates for bios.

I've just reinstalled windows from HDD to SDD and had same problem, bios was too old(but my laptop was no more than 1 y/o). Also you could update firmware on your SSD, but I don't see it necessary.